# PHP Secure Remote Proxy Server Health

Tags: php, proxy, security

Want to be alerted when a secure remote proxy server stop working; for instance if Apache hangs for some reason.

As the remote machine will still be up, will still be able to `ping`, though this would prove very little.

Need to be able to script something that requests a path through the proxy and then returns the result.

Investigated PHP/PEAR Net [library](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=16&catname=Networking), thinking something like `Net_traceroute()` could be a starting point, but can't figure out how to force the route through the server.

Any ideas? Should I even be using PHP or would another language make this easier?

Cheers,

AJ

Comment: removed "Health" tag, as usage of this tag is conventionally for human health, not as a euphemism for proper functioning of a device or system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an HTTP request through the proxy, which I guess is the case because you mention Apache as the proxy?, then you could use [cURL](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php). Probably something like this:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com');

//don't fetch the actual page, you only want to check the connection is ok
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

//stop it from outputting stuff to stdout
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//proxy settings
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxyhost');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:password');

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result === false) {
    die (curl_error($curl)); 
}
```

There are more options for cURL documented [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).